# Android chat application using parse.com.How to check if there are new messages in database?

Tags: android, parse-platform, chat

I am creating a chat application using parse.com. I have created a parseobject and save all the mesaages in the parseobject. The problem is how and when to query database to check for new messages. Currently I am using a android OS handler to query database after 1000 milliseconds but it is very badly affecting the performance of device. Since chat contains images also so that approach is not working. . I am thinking to query database on receive of push notification but I am not sure if that is a correct approach. Please suggest some solutions to resolve this issue. Thanks

Comment: Don't query based on handlers - you'll either lose the connection when the device falls asleep, or prevent it from sleeping (if using AlarmManager, for example). Instead, have your backend send a GCM push to your device. When the device gets that push, it should query the database for new messages.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I was closing the handler on activity onPause method therefore connection lost was not there. I will implement it on push :)

Comment: By the way you should look into cloud could to perform the pushes.

Comment: Gcm pushes are there but I will have to trigger that database event in push receive.